# Hide non-sequential categories from geom_bar and facet_grid chart in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar, facet-grid

When I build a ggplot bar chart that is divided (facet_grid) by category, how do I get rid of empty bars?

Example:

```
library(ggplot2) 

species = c('ash', 'daisy', 'maple', 'iris', 'oak', 'marigold')
category = c('tree', 'flower', 'tree', 'flower', 'tree', 'flower')
mean = c(34, 10, 45, 15, 50, 11)

df = data.frame(species, category, mean)
```

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=species, y=mean)) + 
   geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
   position=position_dodge()) +
   facet_grid(~category)
```

Result:
[image: Sample bar chart showing what needs changing]

I want to remove ash, maple, and oak from the flower chart and daisy, iris, and marigold from the tree chart because there are no data for these species in those categories. Can ggplot do this without subsetting datasets?

Thanks from a puzzled botanist!

Comment: Use `facet_grid(~category, scales = "free_x")`.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!